# NPM can't install Less correctly due to Ruby

Tags: ruby, node.js, less

I am trying to update my LESS version to the latest, but am running into some trouble due to some Ruby stuff I did in the past.

If I run `sudo npm install -g less`, the output path is

`/usr/local/bin/lessc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less@2.7.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less`

But nowhere in my `node_modules`directory is there a less folder.

`which less` outputs
`/usr/bin/less`

Checking the version with `lessc -v` results in:
`lessc 1.7.0 (LESS Compiler) [Ruby] 2.6.0`
Which is obviously wrong. The npm install output showed it installing 2.7.2
I think Ruby / rbenv is hijacking the process, and I'm not sure what to do.

For what it's worth, my $PATH:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/myaccount/local/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/myaccount/local/node/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-2.1.2-2010.02/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-2.1.2-2010.02/bin`

I think my bash profile got screwed up along the way a long time ago, and now it's coming back to haunt me. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I think `/usr/bin/less` refers to less text editor. Maybe you have installed less js locally. check `which lessc` and local `node_modules`

Comment: which lessc gives `/Users/myaccount/.rbenv/shims/lessc`

Comment: I think the only simple way is to add absolute path for lessc in package.json

Comment: `less` has been around for decades in the UNIX world as an alternative to `more`. `lessc` is a different thing.